# angle brackets when selecting a block of text in vim in visual mode

Tags: vim

Whenever I select a block of text in normal mode and then hit `:` to write a command `:'<,'>` sign appears. What is the use/meaning of this.It does not happen when I have not selected a block of text or using normal mode.

I am using gnome terminal in manjaro.

Answer (score 2):

Editing-related Ex commands (the commands you type after `:`, like `:s`) work on a line, this is an "address":

```
" the line is not specified so current line is assumed
:s/foo/bar

" works on the current line
:.s/foo/bar

" works on line 5
:5s/foo/bar
```

or on several lines, this is a "range":

```
" works on lines from 5 through 10
:5,10s/foo/bar
```

Vim is not limited to line numbers: you can use lots of things that can ultimately be turned into a line number. For example:

```
" works on the second line above the current line
:-2s/foo/bar

" works on lines from mark 'a through next occurrence of "potemkine"
:'a,/potemkine/s/foo/bar
```

In this case…

- `'<` is an automatic mark placed by Vim at the beginning of the last visual selection,
- `'>` is another automatic mark placed by Vim at the end of the last visual selection,
- `'<,'>` is a range that covers the last visual selection.

Since you were in visual mode before pressing `:`, Vim assumes that you want to do something with the selection and helpfully inserts the appropriate range for you.

See `:help :range`, `:help '<`, and `:h v_:`.